# PCA: axis of least inertia or of greatest variance

Tags: pca, descriptive-statistics, unsupervised-learning

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5yQ0lBjmVo&t=56), it is said that:

```
The axis of least inertia [is the axis] of greatest variance.
```

However, this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/441917/for-pca-the-best-axis-for-the-projection-of-the-points-is-the-one-who-has-the-m) says the axis of least inertia is also the axis of least variance, which makes sense to me.  So is the video incorrect?  What am I missing here?

Comment: What does the lecturer and/or you mean 'least inertia'? We can factor the covariance matrix and order the vectors (potentially not uniquely if one eigenvalue occurs more than once) according to the absolute values of the eigenvalues... what is the inertia then?

Comment: The book that is quoted in the link says the same as the video. It is only said that it could reportedly be the opposite but no source is given.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the answer:

The confusion comes from the use of axes.  For the same axis, the amount of variance (sum of distance from point to axis) is **the same** as the inertia.

However, the video refers to the variance about the **red** axis ($\lambda_1$, the principal eigenvector) and the inertia about the **green** axis, which explains the statement in question.

[image: img1]